# function that can work with function with different type signatures

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function in haskell that takes two parameters and a function. Depending on the two parameters it will perform the given function or not. The problem is that the given functions can have a different type signatures. In pseudo code:

```
functionB:: String -> IO()


functionC:: String -> String -> IO() 

functionA :: String -> String ->(???)-> IO()
functionA parm1 parm2 f = if parm1 == parm2
                          then f
                          else hPutStrLn "error"
```

FunctionA should be able to work with function C or B and as you can see B and C have a different type signature. Can you do this in Haskell? If so what will be the type signature of functionA?

Comment: That seems like a XY problem. You wouldn't do something like this in Haskell. What's your _actual_ problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You can't write a function that takes either a `String -> IO()` or a `String -> String -> IO() ` as parameter. You'd need `Either (String -> IO()) (String -> String -> IO())`. (But over-reliance of `IO ()` is a strong sign that you're trying to write a program in a different language.)

Comment: `hPutStrLn` takes a `Handle` as its first argument, not a `String`.  Assuming you meant to use `putStrLn`, the type of the expression in the `else` is `IO ()`, and the type of the expression in the `then` must have the same type.  Therefore, if you change `hPutStrLn` to `putStrLn`, the `(???)` must have type `IO ()`, so neither `functionB` nor `functionC` can be passed.

Comment: @molbdnilo, that's not strictly true.  `f :: (String -> a) -> IO ()` would accept either `String -> IO ()` or `String -> String -> IO ()` (as well as any other function whose first argument was of type `String`).  Now, whether you could make a useful function with that type is another matter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for a function to have "two different signatures" based on an argument.  The function will really only have one most general signature, but you can fake it so it works like that.

```
functionA :: String -> String -> a -> a
functionA parm1 parm2 f = if parm1 == parm2 
                          then f
                          else putStrLn "error" -- uh oh
```

The signature says that this will return the same kind of thing as its third argument. So:

```
functionA "foo" "bar" functionB :: String -> IO ()
functionA "foo" "bar" functionC :: String -> String -> IO ()
```

In other words, the first line takes one additional argument (four total), and the second line takes two (five total).

The trouble is that it doesn't work, because `putStrLn "error"` doesn't have either of those types, and we need it to have "both".

One way through this is to make a typeclass which characterizes the operations you need on both of those types.  In this case, maybe printing an error is the thing you want?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class CanPrintError a where
    printError :: String -> a

instance CanPrintError (IO ()) where
    -- specialized to:
    -- printError :: String -> IO ()
    printError = putStrLn

instance (CanPrintError b) => CanPrintError (a -> b) where
    -- specialized to:
    -- printError :: (CanPrintError b) => String -> a -> b
    printError err _ = printError err
```

Notice that I have made the second instance recursive, so `CanPrintError` doesn't only have instances for `String -> IO ()` and `String -> String -> IO ()`, it has instances for all multiple-arg functions ending in `IO ()` such as

```
String -> Int -> (Int -> Maybe Bool) -> IO ()
```

It is possible to just make it for the two specific types in question, though it makes me question your motivations.

Now we just add the necessary constraint to `functionA`'s signature:

```
functionA :: (CanPrintError a) => String -> String -> a -> a
functionA parm1 parm2 f = if parm1 == parm2
                          then f
                          else printError "error"
```

You can imagine substituting for `printError` whatever operation you need to do.  This is pretty much what typeclasses are for. :-)

However, I do suggest posting a question with more specific details of your problem, since it smells like something that might have a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

The function `const` creates a new function that always returns the first parameter regardless of what you pass to it. It's type signature is:

```
const :: a -> b -> a
```

This means we can create things like:

```
> const 4 "String"
4

> let fn = const (\x -> print x)
> :t fn
fn :: Show a => b -> a -> IO ()
> fn [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] (Just 3)
Just 3
```

In your example, you can use this function to pass a "`const`'d" version of `functionB` to `functionA`:

```
functionB x = putStrLn x
functionC x y = putStrLn x >> putStrLn y 

functionA :: String -> String -> (String -> String -> IO()) -> IO()
functionA parm1 parm2 f = if parm1 == parm2
                          then f parm1 parm2
                          else putStrLn "error"

> functionA "Foo" "Foo" (const functionB)
Foo
> functionA "Foo" "Foo" functionC
Foo
Foo
> functionA "Foo" "Bar" undefined
error
```

Answer (score 0):

The given code wouldn't perform as expected. As mentioned above, `hPutStrln` requires a file handle, did you intend `putStrLn`? If so, the signature of `putStrLn` is `String -> IO ()` and so `putStrLn "error"` is just `IO ()`. Since the line `else f` provides no argument for f, the type signature of f must be `IO ()` - the type signature would be `functionA :: String -> String -> IO () -> IO ()` (actually, it could be `functionA :: Eq t => t -> t -> IO () -> IO ()` since the there is nothing requiring a string yet).

The problem is if you can't make it so that f can take in one or two inputs, it only only be or the other. You could replace `else f` with `else f parm1` and then f would be of type `String -> IO ()` or with `else parm1 parm2` and then f would be of type `String -> String -> IO ()`.